# Rotating an object based on UI input

Tags: android, user-interface, opengl-es, 3d

I want to rotate a object(Some thing like 3d cube ) without touching the surface , say I have a specific x,y,z axis UI  and when I change this axis value From the UI , It in turn should turn the 3D object .

Comment: Show us what you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation of your object, when being drawn, is set by some variables (a rotation matrix, or a quaternion or such).

Your UI will provide some values, either by widgets you retrieve the values from or by sending events. Using these values you adjust the drawing controlling variable and issue a full redraw of the scene.

---

OpenGL is not a scene graph. It doesn't maintain a scene, it just draws points, lines or triangles to a pixel based framebuffer. As soon as a primitive (point, line, triangle) has been drawn OpenGL has no recollection about it whatsoever. You want something altered => >ou redraw the whole scene.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're looking for is a "track ball".  Here's some info:

[Trackball](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Trackball)

Comment: OP was asking specifically about not using a Trackball ("without touching the surface"); OP's problem is something different anyway.

Comment: But it contradicted itself, because he said "it changes from the UI", which implies a UI, which implies something else I'm not sure what.

Comment: I was thinking about numeric inputs. You know, SpinBoxes, sliders, dials, stuff like that.